# checking a char pointer for NULL in strstr

Tags: c, strstr

I was trying to implement strstr in C
but I was stuck at this piece of code which was crashing at runtime

```
while (*a==*b && a != NULL && b != NULL) {
    a++
    b++
}
if (b == NULL || *b == '\0') { // string found }
```

After googling for sometime I figured out the mistake
https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/tcl80/src/tcl8.0/compat/strstr.c

I should've had my loop do the following:

```
while (*a==*b && *a != 0 && *b != 0) {
    a++
    b++
}
if (*b === 0) { // string found }
```

But I'm still not clear on why wouldn't the first approach work as well?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `a != NULL` is not the same  as `*a != 0`.

Recall that a string is an array of characters up to and including the terminating null character `'\0'`.  Rather than pass around strings, code typically passes a pointer to the first character.

`a != NULL` tests if that pointer is equal to `NULL`.  A pointer with the value `NULL` is never a string.  It is simply a pointer to a location that will never have any valid data.

`*a != 0` tests if the pointer `a`, let us assume it is of type `char *`, points to a `char` that does not have the value of of the null character `'\0'` as that would be the end of the string.  Thus the loop should stop.

---

Note: the loop could be simplified.  By the time code reaches `*b != 0`, it already can not have the value of `'\0'`.

```
// while (*a==*b && *a != 0 && *b != 0) {
while (*a==*b && *a != 0) {
    a++
    b++
}
// if (*b === 0) { // string found }  Type use ==, not ===
if (*b == 0) { // string found }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to deference the pointer to compare it's value.